# mdctextinputcontrollerunderline not detected

Tags: material-components-ios

i've been trying to implementation Material design on iOS, i'm using google material components

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

   let userNameTextField : MDCTextField  = {
            let textFieldFloating = MDCTextField()
            textFieldFloating.placeholder = "Full Name"
            return textFieldFloating
        }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    view.addSubview(m_userNameTextField)
    m_userNameTextField.acnchor(top: signUpButton.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 40, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 40, width: 0, height: 200 )
        m_userNameTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate

        let mUsernameController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline 
        mUsernameController = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: m_userNameTextField)

        super.viewDidLoad()
      }
}
```

the MDCTextInputControllerUnderline get error :

Use of unresolved identifier 'MDCTextInputControllerUnderline'

Comment: Have you resolved this issue >

Comment: i am getting same error. Please update answer